# Android Studio emulator CPU monitoring not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, cpu-usage, ddms, android-studio-2.2

I need to inspect the CPU load of my application on `Android API` from level `16` to `19`.

I launch the emulator (`armeabi-v7a` architecture) and then I build and run the app.

I go to `Android Monitor > Monitors` and the `CPU` monitor is not showing any data.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm targeting the right device and the right package.. the Memory usage is fine, I don't care about Network data.

What am I missing?

NB: I've currently tested it with an emulator with API level `16` and `17` then stopped since I want to solve this problem before.